# How to prevent SSL connections for some Virtual Hosts in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I'm using Name based Virtual Hosts on ports 80 and 443.  Some of the virtual hosts only support port 80.  I don't have, and won't be getting certificates for these hostnames.

How can I configure apache to refuse a connection on port 443 to one of the host names?

Eg:

`supportsboth.example.com`  has a certificate, can listen on port 80 and port 443

`httponly.example.org` does not have a certificate, should be available via regular HTTP only.

The apache configuration has a virtualhost setting entry for `supportsboth.example.com` on port 443 only.

Trying to connect to `httponly.example.com` on port 443 makes Apache use the `supportsboth.example.com` virtual host's certificate and details.

This makes the browser report lots of certificate errors as the host names don't match, and if the user decides to proceed anyway, it still ends up at the wrong site.

What I'd ideally like is a redirect to the HTTP site, but I imagine that would rely on having a valid certificate.  My second preference is to simply refuse the connection.

Micheal's answer below of putting the SSL capable names on a separate IP is not available to me as both the domains have already been configured to use the same IP and I'm not in a position to change them.

Comment: `putting the SSL capable names on a separate IP is not available` - Then you are SOL?

Comment: I suppose you could setup some kind of Frankenstein monster of a reverse proxy with filtering, but it would be better to get a spare IP, and fix DNS.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that.  Looks like the same issue.  And Micheal's given the same answer.

Comment: Well I'll be... you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different IP address for the hosts which should never answer on SSL, and ensure that Apache only listens on port 443 for the appropriate IP addresses.

Comment: I would accept this obviously correct answer except that I didn't ask this question soon enough and now the host names are assigned to the same address and I'm not in a position to change that.

Comment: Well, then, you will have to find the person who is in a position to change it.

Comment: IF ONLY you could change DNS entries once they've been set up. Sadly, you're stuck with this mistake forever.